# about if and while statement in java programming?

Tags: java

These are kind of broad question not about a specific program.

But say you have a while statement

like this

```
while(conditions){
    statement
}
```

Say you if statement is an if statement.

Would you do

```
while(conditions){
    if(condtion){
        statment
    }
}
```

Would this be right?

Another question about the if statement is that it does not always need an else part correct.

For example you can do

```
if(condition)
;(empty statment)

statement
```

Meaning it either meets the condition or it does nothing.

Comment: What's the sense of checking the statement twice?

Comment: Not really clear what you're asking here...

Comment: Specific concrete examples would help us understand question in better way.

Comment: For me it's clear, what he was asking. He asked if it's reasonable to put an if-statement into an while-statement: NO that doesn't make any sense, because you will check your condition twice. Yes you don't need an else-statement with an if.

Comment: OK I will ask someting more specific.

Comment: Edit the same question and maybe it will get reopened.

Comment: Why so many thumb down for only asking a question yall think you so good in java that everyone else is an idiot..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have an if statement in a while statement, etc, and instead of doing else, you can do:

```
if(!bool) return "bool isn't true";
```

Instead of doing

```
if(bool){}else{return "bool isn't true";}
```

Replace bool with whatever value you want to compare.

You may replace bool with things like `x>y`(if x is greater than y) or a `boolean` value that you have defined.